# google sheet script filter and query based on checkbox and date

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 2 sheets.
1 sheet with 3 columns: 1 column with dates, 1 column with data and one with checkboxes

The other sheet I want to apply the query on
If a checkbox is checked that copy a row with specific column based on the date of 2 cells on the target sheet. (one cell contains month (januari, second cell contains year 2023)

The query part works:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:D, "select B,A,C where D=TRUE")
```

But then howto integrate the date filter.  I need some guidance, sometimes I cant get my head around it.

```
=QUERY(filter(Data!A1:D100, "select B,A,C,D where D=TRUE",TEXT(Data!A1:A100,"yyyMMMM") = $D$1 & $B$1))
```

Latest code I came up with, but does not work.

Suggestions are welcome

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hi. Please provide some dummy data to demonstrate the contents of each sheet, the values that appear in cells C8 and F8 and an example of a successful outcome. Issues:1) You say "1 sheet with 3 columns (including checkboxes)" but your query (`=QUERY(Transacties!A8:G; "select B,A,C where G=TRUE")`)shows four columns. 2) You say C8 contains the month but you describe a text value for a month). 3) your sample query references Cell C14 but you don't describe the content of this cell.

Comment: I am sorry it is  a little bit confusing. I added a link to sheet to make it more clear

Comment: Please edit your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Your sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Ok, used your link to create a new table. Changed question to reflect this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` with two criteria, like this:

```
=filter( 
  { Data!B1:B, Data!A1:A, Data!C1:C }, 
  Data!D1:D, 
  text(Data!A1:A, "MMMyyyy") = left(B1, 3) & D1 
)
```

...where column `Data!A1:A` contains numeric date values, cell `B1` contains a month name as a text string and `D1` contains a year as a number.

Comment: Thank you, but I dont understand how it takes the checkbox into account. I see you take column D into the range but then I am puzzled.

Comment: `filter()` expects [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) criteria. Column `Data!D1:D` contains Booleans from the get-go, so comparing its values against `true` would be superfluous. `true = true` is the same as `true`, and `false = true` is the same as `false`.

Comment: Thank you verry much. I had a little trouble deploying this into my real sheet. I had to change the , with \  to stack the columns. (and the , in ; ofcourse) All in all it is working fine now. Learned a lot today :-)